# как достать из pdf проекта сделанного в AutoCAD цифры, а после заменить старые цифры, используя только консоль линукса

Tags: linux, консоль, pdf, autocad

Нужно достать цифры

Сделать операции

И поставить новые назад на те же места

Terminal only

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Тебе наверное пакет `poppler-utils` нужен.

Comment: Просто даже если я достал цифры, там только цифры, как из текстового или другого формата файла сделать обратно pdf с изменениями

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример того,  как это должно работать. Сейчас трудно понять, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Прикрепил изображение

Comment: Это pdf нужно из него достать цифры
Изменить их
И сделать обратно pdf уже с правками, и все через терминал.

Comment: Главная проблема, вставить в pdf цифры из терминала на те же места

Comment: а пдфку скинешь?

Comment: https://file.io/KfPPTTkCHwQU

Answer (score 0):

Понадобится инструмент. Этот подойдет чтоб получить читабельный код из того файла

```
sudo apt install mupdf-tools
```

Распакуем потоки внутри файла

```
mutool clean -d 1.pdf m1.pdf
```

В нем будет доступен текст. В этом документе текст выводится командой Tj

```
grep -a -E "Tj|Tm"  m1.pdf
```

В команде Tm стоят координаты текста

```
1 0 0 1 12589 51734 Tm
(2.27) Tj
1 0 0 1 20014 51734 Tm
(2.25) Tj
0 -1 1 0 30407 45125 Tm
(3.01) Tj
0 -1 1 0 30407 35225 Tm
(3.00) Tj
0 -1 1 0 30407 25324 Tm
(3.00) Tj
0 -1 1 0 30407 15424 Tm
(3.00) Tj
0 -1 1 0 30407 8062 Tm
(1.50) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 49284 Tm
(34) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 29426 Tm
(35) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 9625 Tm
(36) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 49284 Tm
(34) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 29426 Tm
(35) Tj
0 -1 1 0 22250 9625 Tm
(36) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11812 30551 Tm
(-380) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 20651 Tm
(-503) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11812 20651 Tm
(-446) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19237 20651 Tm
(-474) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19231 50352 Tm
(-276) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 30551 Tm
(-437) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11811 50352 Tm
(-248) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11812 40451 Tm
(-314) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 50352 Tm
(-305) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 40451 Tm
(-371) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19231 40451 Tm
(-342) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11812 10750 Tm
(-511) Tj
0 -1 1 0 11819 5800 Tm
(-544) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19231 5800 Tm
(-573) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19231 10750 Tm
(-540) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 10750 Tm
(-568) Tj
0 -1 1 0 26656 5800 Tm
(-601) Tj
0 -1 1 0 19231 30551 Tm
(-408) Tj
```

Даже можно поправить этот текст, но начертание на экране от этого не изменится. Но если выделить мышкой и скопировать - он скопируется с новым значением.

Само начертание закодировано дальше по тексту в вектор командами `l`.

Можно вычистить эти obj и нарисовать новые поверх например через reportlab. Или конвертнуть в svg и разметить там шаблон.